# How do you use custom prompts with LangChains RetrievalQA without specifying from_chain_type?

Tags: python, chatbot, langchain, large-language-model

According to [LangChain's documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/vector_db_qa),

"There are two ways to load different chain types. First, you can specify the chain type argument in the from_chain_type method. This allows you to pass in the name of the chain type you want to use....The above way allows you to really simply change the chain_type, but it doesn't provide a ton of flexibility over parameters to that chain type. If you want to control those parameters, you can load the chain directly."

The difference between the two options is:

```
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(), chain_type="map_reduce", retriever=docsearch.as_retriever())
```

compared to:

```
 qa_chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(temperature=0), chain_type="stuff")
 qa = RetrievalQA(combine_documents_chain=qa_chain, retriever=docsearch.as_retriever())
```

The issue I am running into is that I can't use the second option's flexibility with custom prompts. Running `inspect.getfullargspec(RetrievalQA.from_chain_type)` shows a `chain_type_kwargs` argument, which is how you [pass a prompt](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/prompts/prompt_templates/). There is no `chain_type_kwards` argument in either `load_qa_chain` or `RetrievalQA`. Langchain's documentation does not provide any additional information on how to access the ability to send prompts using the more flexible method. I would like to be able to combine the use of prompts with the ability to change the parameters of the chain type.

Logically, one would things something like this would work:

```
qa_chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(temperature=0), chain_type="stuff")
qa = RetrievalQA(combine_documents_chain=qa_chain, retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(), chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs)
```

But it results in a:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for RetrievalQA chain_type_kwargs extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

As mentioned before, this does work:

```
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff", retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(), chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `prompt=<YOUR PROMPT TEMPLATE FUNCTION` as one of the arguments.